# Pretend Firefox instead of Phantom.js

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, user-agent, http-status-code-405

When I try to scrap [this site](http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb/results/page/) with Phantomjs, by default, Phantomjs send the following headers to server:

```
"name":"User-Agent",
"value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.1 Safari/534.34"}
```

And I get an `status 405 "Not Allowed"` response.

I read in the **Phantomjs API Reference** that in order to imitate a request coming from some other browser, I should change my User-Agent value. On Wikipedia I found the value I should use for pretending to be **Firefox** under **Ubuntu**:

```
'name': 'User-Agent',
'value': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20120815 Firefox/16.0'
```

In what part of Phantomjs should I put this properties? Where should I insert them - inside **page.open**, or inside **page.evaluate**, or at the top of it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually, is on `page.settings`. Do it before the `open`.

Here is an example using it against that page you linked:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36';
page.open('http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb/results/page/', function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var output = page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.getElementById('tournamentTable')
           .getElementsByClassName('deactivate')[0]
           .getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
           .textContent;
        });
        console.log(output);
    }, 1000);
});
```

This example will scrape the match name in first row on the table. (Which, in this precise moment is "`San Francisco Giants - Boston Red Sox`")

---

About your comment, actually you can use jquery under phantomjs! Check this example:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36';
page.open('http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb/results/page/', function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
            var output = page.evaluate(function () {
                return jQuery('#tournamentTable .deactivate:first a:first').text();
            });
            console.log(output);
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

By the way, for waiting, instead of the `window.setTimeout` I used on this examples, I recommend you to use [waitfor.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) instead.

Comment: thanks a lot, its hard to play with `getElementsByClassName` after jQuery > sizzle

Comment: @khaljava Oh but you can use jquery under phantomjs, I just didn't did it like that to keep it simple. Check the updated answer.

Comment: some websites have a way to detect PhantomJS even if you set headers, they return error or blank screen. If I open them in Chrome, everything is fine. I wonder is there a way to deal with it

Comment: @Toolkit tell me one of those websites. They may use browser fingerprint, evaluating  javascript's object `navigator` and others. I will suggest you to use Selenium + Headless Chrome (using flag `--headless`, in chromeOptions)